# Creating array with 256 characters?

Tags: ada

In this task, I must define the data type `String_Type`, which must be able to store text. One
`String_Type` should contain two sub-variables, `Char_Array`, a field of 256 characters, and an integer
`Length` that tells how much of the field is currently being used. Note that `String_Type` is something completely separate from `String` which is already defined in Ada. I have tried to write some code for this task but it seems that I have not understood what this task really wants. My code:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;                    use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;            use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure data is
type String_type is
  record
   array (Positive range <>) of Character;  --Error: Component declaration expected
     Heltal_length: Integer;
  end record;
 P1: String_type;

begin
Put("Write your characters: ");
Get(P1.Char_array);
Put(P1.Char_array);

end data;
```

Comment: I see a *defining_identifier* for the record's length component, but I don't see one for the array; more [here](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-8.html).

Comment: Since `anonymous arrays not allowed as components`, you'll also need a type declaration for the array, e.g. `Char_Array_Type`.

Comment: This sounds remarkably similar to the package Ada.Strings.Bounded described in section A.4.4 of the Language Reference Manual.

Comment: Unbounded string (Name: Unbounded_String;) does not work here (?). The length is fixed to 256 characters.

Comment: Simply instantiate the bounded string with a size of 256. It has all the capabilities you desire.

Answer (score 3):

As Trashgod mentioned, you cannot just define a record field as an array anonymously like you did in your provided example.  Additionally, you need to name your field, which you didn't.  Ada is a "strongly typed" language meaning it relies heavily on knowing the type and there are many rules that require this (there are some relaxed rules, but this is not one of them).

First I would recommend creating a numeric type just for your string's length.  You string can have anything from no letters to all 256 and everywhere inbetween, so I suggest:

```
subtype String_Length is Integer range 0 .. 256;
```

Next you need to create an array type for your String_Type record.  You can use your newly declared length type to help bound your array with the bonus that if you want to change the max size later, all you have to do is change the String_Length type definition and your String_Type will automatically adjust the max length.

```
type Character_Array is array (1..String_Length'Last) of Character;
```

Now you can use these to make a field in your String_Type:

```
type String_Type is record
    Char_Array  : Character_Array;
    Length      : String_Length := 0;
end record;
```

This gives you a nice string type that checks for bad length values.

One side note, I noticed you are trying to use the Get procedure to get both the length and then the character array in your record.  I would recommend instantiating an instance of the generic package Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO(String_Length) and using the Get procedure from that package to read the string length.  Reading the String is a bit trickier since you are using your own custom type and the Get function expects an Ada String, but that wasn't part of your original question, so hopefully you can work that through and figure out an algorithm.  I would recommend using a dummy variable of the Ada string type (sized to match your expected string length) and then use a loop to copy it over to your Char_Array variable.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this seems to set out the type you describe

```
procedure Main is

   type Char_Array_Index is range 1 .. 256;
   type Char_Array is array (Char_Array_Index) of Character;

   type String_Type
     (Size : Char_Array_Index := Char_Array_Index'First) is
      record
         Length : Char_Array_Index;
         Data   : Char_Array;
      end record;

begin
   --  Insert code here.
   null;
end Main;
```

Note the discriminant part parameterising the record. Although not necessarily for strings, this is quite a common pattern in Spark/Ada, when you know you have to allocate *some* space but you're not sure *how* much you'll actually need.

The question did say/imply distinct from String, but this seems unlikely in a real world application, so perhaps using subtypes is a better solution

```
procedure Main is

   subtype Char_Array_Index is Positive range 1 .. 256;
   subtype Char_Array is String (Char_Array_Index);

   type String_Type
     (Size : Char_Array_Index := Char_Array_Index'First) is
      record
         Length : Char_Array_Index;
         Data   : Char_Array;
      end record;

begin
   --  Insert code here.
   null;
end Main;
```

Using subtypes like this means interoperability with the native String type becomes much easier, so you should be able to use Ada.Text_IO's Get and Put subprograms without too much bother.

EDIT: both these examples do not support an empty Data field, they must always have a minimum length of Char_Array_Index'First, and initialisation of Data needs to be considered appropriately.

Comment: And how do you call the length and Data in the main function? I tried to call it by using: "A: String_Type;"  after the end record and then call it in the Main by writing "Get(A.Length)" but I got a compiler error.

Comment: Why do you have both `Size` and `Length`?

Comment: @XerxesGoogle It's becaues the type of A.Length is not the same type as the procedure Get is expecting (probably expects either a String or an integer depending on what you "withed" in).  If you want to use a Get call on A.Length, you need to instantiate the generic package Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO(Char_Array_Index) and then use the Get operation from that package